# find the angle of a suspended lamina, check the photo for the full question

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

[Centre of mass related question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmhDy.jpg)

I don't understand how to tackle this question, I know how to find the centre of mass of the shape but don't know what is the next step.

Comment: Post this is physics SE.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line from the COM coordinates you found to point C in the diagram.  This line makes an angle with the horizontal a point C (call the angle $\theta$).  If you took a compass and drew a circle with the radius extending from point C to the COM coordinates, the bottom of the circle would be the minimum potential energy.  The angle it makes with the vertical is just $\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta$